# Call finally if requst processing fails in jax-rs/jersey

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to implement a logic similar to what i've done with Spring:

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyContext.clear();
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MyContext.clear();
        }
    }
```

Finally here ensures that even if somewhere down the line of request processing something bad happens we still clear the context. It is important because we've faced an issue of context pollution when a thread with already initialized context is later reused (context in this case is an InheritableThreadLocal containing some value associated with a particular request).

The problem is, i don't see a way to do something similar with jax-rs - filters are not supposed to know anything about the chain it seems so obviously `finally` on a `ContainerRequestFilter` only works within this filter, not the whole chain.
Where can i place `finally` block so that it would be called when request processing fails?

Comment: Maybe use a [RequestEventListener](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16058)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha tuns out we're going with RestEasy after all and in there RestEasyContext exists to hold all of your contexts and clean them up after request is processed.
RequestEventListener would've helped in jersey though, so thank you very much for suggestion.